# Update subscriptions with new publisher

Tags: sql-server, database, replication

We are upgrade the database server to new hardware. It has several publications for database replication. We cannot re-initialize the replication for existing subscriptions due to the size of the databases. Is there a way to just update the subscriptions to switch to the new server?

Comment: There is a way to do this but it is not officially supported by Microsoft. The approach is detailed here: https://blog.pythian.com/migrate-sql-server-environment-complex-replication-without-reinitializing-rebuilding-replication/

Comment: Note that the new server needs to have the same name as the old server for everything to work and you'll need to test the migration thoroughly before doing it in production.